# Comparing two fields in django queryset

Tags: mysql, django

How would I do the following SQL query in the Django ORM?

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date_added > date_created;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't have the `date_created` available as a variable (as @tttthomasssss assumes) so it will be something like this:

```
from django.db import models

YourTable.objects.filter(date_added__gt=models.F('date_created')
```

Docs on F expressions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions

Comment: true, I assumed that both were given as the OP didn't specify it, would opt for yours if not :)

Comment: What if our field is placed in a relation, such as: 'order__date_created' ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__gt` for `>`: `MyModel.objects.filter(date_added__gt=date_created)`.

See the documentation for querysets [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/).

**EDIT:**
If `date_created` isn't available to you, then @Wolph's solution is the one.

Comment: I think this won't work, because date_created is not available. This line would raise a NameError.

Comment: Either your or my answer is correct, let's see what David actually means :)

Answer (score 1):

You can [use F() expressions in queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model) like this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(date_added__gt=F('date_created'))
```